# Spurious edit failures

Tags: bug, edits

Today, multiple times, I've saved an edit and seen the orange popup saying that the edit save has failed... but actually it's worked, and reloading the page shows the change.

It's not happening on *every* edit, although possibly every edit on one machine (I've got my home laptop and work laptop going at the same time). I'm happy to provide any more information that would help - it's quite disconcerting...

Comment: may be a cache problem, it happens sometimes

Comment: And Jon finally reveals his secrets: answering from two computers simultaneously!

Comment: @Lucifer I don't understand what kind of cache problem you're suggesting would cause this; care to explain?

Answer (score 12):

According to our logs, the server returned a 302 redirect to some of your edit submissions. This is the correct response if the edit was made from the actual edit page (e.g. like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/133617/edit)), as in this case it's a standard POST/Redirect/GET. But since your edits are inline edits this should not happen; instead, you should receive a 200 response with a JSON object (inline edit submissions are AJAX requests). Trying to parse the response as JSON would thus fail, causing the error message.

To check whether an edit submission is inline or not (they hit the same route), we use .NET's `IsAjaxRequest()`, which (so [the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523827/asp-net-mvc-what-does-isajaxrequest-actually-mean) tells me) simply checks for the `X-Requested-With` HTTP header which jQuery sets when making AJAX requests.

The fact that the server responds with a 302 therefore suggests that this header wasn't received. The obvious theory here is that the machine where these failures occur is sitting behind a proxy that strips this header, or something similar; maybe you could check that?

Comment: That's entirely feasible - it's on a VPN from home. I'm very happy to check anything - what's the simplest way of doing so? (Any jQuery test-beds you know of which would show the headers received, for example?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Go to http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php (or a similar site) and put `var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.open("get", "", true); req.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"); req.onreadystatechange = function () { document.body.parentElement.innerHTML = req.responseText; }; req.send();` into the JavaScript console, that should replace the page content with the data for the Ajax request. It should contain the X-Requested-With header.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it (on the "broken" machine) - it came back with X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: What if you replace "get" with "post"?

Comment: Sorry, only just seen this. Trying now...

Comment: Okay, that's weird... I've just tried it with both get *and* post, and in neither case did it show the X-Requested-With. I wonder whether I've switched between proxies silently, or something like that.